# Java get mouseover tooltip text

Tags: java, tooltip

Is it possible in java (or any other language that you know of) to get tool tip text (on mouseover). For example you mouseover something in an arbitrary application and a tiny tooltip pops up with some info. Can this be returned as a string to a program. It seems possible, i dont see why not but im no expert. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All the classes which extend `JComponent` have these functionalities.

- You do :

  ```
  comp.setToolTipText("HEY!");
  ```

  to set the text.
- You do :

  ```
  String tt = comp.getToolTipText();
  ```

  to get the text.

Answer (score 3):

```
JButton b = new JButton("button1");
b.setToolTipText("click here to submit");
```

here is an example on how to add a tooltop to a jbutton. but here is the thing
you dont have to write action listners to your button so that pop menu will become visible on mouse over . tooltip text will be automatically work on mouseOver.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [How to Use Tool Tips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html).

Also see `JComponent` [getTooltipText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipText--) method.